# Heroku Mixed content HTTPS/HTTP issue

Tags: javascript, heroku, https, mean-stack

I deployed my app to Heroku and I keep getting this error in the Chrome console:

```
bundle.js:11892 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://***.herokuapp.com/#/login' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint    
'http://localhost:3000/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must 
be served over HTTPS.(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:11892sendReq @ 
bundle.js:11653serverRequest @ bundle.js:11363processQueue @ 
bundle.js:16097(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:16113Scope.$eval @ 
bundle.js:17365Scope.$digest @ bundle.js:17181Scope.$apply @   
bundle.js:17473(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:25159defaultHandlerWrapper @ 
bundle.js:3592eventHandler @ bundle.js:3580
bundle.js:11892 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/login. Failed     
to start loading.
```

This is my server file:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let publicRouter = express.Router();
let apiRouter = express.Router();
let models = require(__dirname + '/models');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let morgan = require('morgan');
let config = require(__dirname + '/config/env.js');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, token, authorization');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
 next();
})

require(__dirname + '/routes/auth-routes')(publicRouter, models);
require(__dirname + '/routes/users-routes')(apiRouter, models);
require(__dirname + '/routes/questions-routes')(apiRouter, models);
require(__dirname + '/routes/scores-routes')(apiRouter, models);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', publicRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  console.log('server started on port ' + config.PORT);
});
```

I tried changing all the localhost:3000 routes to https but that did not help. I figured that wouldn't work haha. I thought it may be the google font but this is the link "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=xxx+xxx+xxx" which should be good to go for HTTPS. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js or service or where you're making your calls to the server in your app change the address from localhost:3000 to https://***.herokuapp.com:443/yourendpoint. So like

```
$http.get("https://***.herokuapp.com:443/api).then(function(response) {
...some code...;
})
```

also "//***.herokuapp.com:443" should work as well

Comment: My API path from local is like... `http://gisapi-web-staging-1636833739.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/v2`. So what should be my path when deployed to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

https is on 443. perhaps, change your server to listen on that port instead of 8080.