# Enabling https on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have an app running on Heroku with an Node Express.js backend with a simple API, and a React.js frontend. Requests are proxied to the backend (`http://localhost:5000`).

When I ping the API from React however, I get the following error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://**.herokuapp.com/users' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://localhost:5000/api/users'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

How can I make the resource secure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku Mixed content HTTPS/HTTP issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129228/heroku-mixed-content-https-http-issue)

Comment: @Mikko does this mean changing the React proxy to be `https://**.herokuapp.com/api`? Does this mean the API would be publicly accessible, since anyone can ping that address?